# How to pass variables to slot methods in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm making a little chat messenger program, which needs a list of chat channels the user has joined. To represent this list graphically, I have made a list of `QPushButtons`, which all represent a different channel. These buttons are made with the following method, and that's where my problem kicks in:

```
void Messenger::addToActivePanels(std::string& channel)
{
    activePanelsContents = this->findChild<QWidget *>(QString("activePanelsContents"));
    pushButton = new QPushButton(activePanelsContents);
    pushButton->setObjectName("pushButton");
    pushButton->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 60, 60));
    pushButton->setText("");
    pushButton->setToolTip(QString(channel.c_str()));
    pushButton->setCheckable(true);
    pushButton->setChecked(false);
    connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(switchTab(channel)));
}
```

(activePanelContents is a QWidget that holds the list.)

The point is that each button should call the `switchTab(string& tabname)` method when clicked, including the specific channel's name as variable. This implementation doesn't work though, and I haven't been able to find out how to properly do this.

Answer (score 8):

For strings and integers, you can use QSignalMapper.  In your `Messenger` class, you would add a `QSignalMapper mapper` object, and your function would look like:

```
void Messenger::addToActivePanels(std::string& channel)
{
    activePanelsContents = this->findChild<QWidget *>(QString("activePanelsContents"));
    pushButton = new QPushButton(activePanelsContents);
    // ...
    connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &mapper, SLOT(map()));
    mapper.setMapping(pushButton, QString(channel.c_str()));
}
```

and after you have added all channels to your active panels, you call

```
connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)), this, SLOT(switchTab(const QString &)));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... switchTab() simply never gets called, although no errors are given anywhere at all.

Comment: Does `switchTab()` take a `const QString &`?  If it doesn't, you need to change it so it does.  Qt doesn't allow you to pass `std::string` (or, in general, any type not registered with `qRegisterMetaType`) through signals and slots.  Typos inside `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are not detected until runtime, because those macros turn their arguments into strings.  Chances are Qt is printing an error message to the console when it tries to make the connection to `switchTab(const QString &)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `QSignalMapper` to pass variables;

```
        QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();


         signalMapper -> setMapping (button, <data>) ;
         connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this,   
                   SLOT(buttonClicked(QString))) ;
```

in slot i.e

```
void class::buttonClicked(QString data){

    //use data
    // to get sender 
    QSignalMapper *temp = (QSignalMapper *)this->sender();
    QPushButton *btn = (QPushButton *)temp->mapping(data);
    // use btn

}
```

Hope my ans may help you

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was using QSignalMapper with QTNetworkRequest and didn't know i had to use Mapper->mapping(data) to obtain the object in such a case. I was simply using  qobject_cast<QObject*>(sender) which only works when you have no parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the sender method unless you absolutely have to.  It ties the function directly to being used only as a slot (can't be called directly).  Retain the behavior of having the function accept a string and simply make a mechanism by which you can call it.

One method, among others you might find, is to leverage use of QSignalMapper.  It will map objects to values and regenerate signals of the appropriate signature.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with "relay" objects:

Create `TabSwitchRelay` which is a sub-class of `QObject` with this constructor:

```
TabSwitchRelay::TabSwitchRelay(QObject *parent, Messanger * m, const QString & c)
: QObject(parent), m_messanger(m), m_channel(c)
{
}
```

It also has a slot `clicked()`:

```
void TabSwitchRelay::clicked()
{
    m_messager->switchTab(m_channel);
}
```

Now replace the line in your code that does connect with this:

```
TabSwitchRelay * tabRelay = new TabSwitchRelay(pushButton, this, channel);
connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), tabRelay, SLOT(clicked()));
```

It's not tested but you get teh basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having your `switchTab` slot take no argument and use [`QObject::sender`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qobject.html#sender) to get the object that sent the signal.

```
Messenger::switchTab()
{
  QObject* sender = this->sender();
  QPushButton* button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender);
  if(button)
  {
    // Do stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware of the warnings before using the QObject::sender in your code

Comment: Not sure why your post was minused, but thanks anyway. You helped  a lot

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Qt5, you can do it through lambda:

```
connect( sender, &Sender::valueChanged,  [=](){ myMethod(5); } );

void myMethod(int value)
{
  // do stuff
}
```