# Qt QThread trouble using signal/slot going from worker to gui

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a Qt application that was developed using Qt Creator and the GUI tool that accompanies it. I have a main thread, `TheGui` and a worker thread that is created by the main thread, `WorkerThread` (called `thread`).

The problem I'm having is when I create a slot in the GUI by using

```cxx
public slot:
  void updateTable(string str);
```

within the header file of the GUI and signal `void sendList(string str);` within the header file of the worker thread, the slot never gets called. I connected the two using

```cxx
connect(&thread, SIGNAL(sendList(string str),
        this,    SLOT(updateTable(string str)));
```

within the constructor in the GUI cpp file. I did something similar except with the slot in the worker thread and signal from the GUI and it worked fine. I know from using the debugger that the signal sendList is indeed getting called, it is just never going into it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927860/how-to-pass-variables-to-slot-methods-in-qt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because the signal and the slot are on distinct threads, the connection between them has the `Qt::QueuedConnection` type. And for queued connections, Qt has to be able to save a copy of the signal parameters, to pass them later to the slot.

    So, to inform Qt that the type is copyable, you have to register it with Qt's meta-object system (see [QMetaType](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qmetatype.htm)) like this:

   ```
   // This macro call should be put in one of your .h files 
   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string)

   // You should call this function before any (queued) 
   // signal/slot connection involving the type
   qRegisterMetaType<std::string>();
   ```
2. The parameter name shouldn't be included in the `QObject::connect` call, and the type names should be exactly the same as the ones you passed to `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`:

   ```
   connect(&thread, SIGNAL(sendList(std::string), this, SLOT(updateTable(std::string)));
   ```

You can also use `QString` or `QByteArray`, which are already registered, instead of `std::string`, since these functions are slots and signals and as such are already Qt specific.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually got around this for the time being by using pointers. Where would I call qRegisterMetaType? I keep getting error 'instantiated from 'int qMetaTypeId(T*)[with T=StringVector]' where StringVector is what I'm trying to declare.

Comment: @Kyle Maybe you didn't include the header file where you used Q_DECLARE_METATYPE in the .cpp file where you called qRegisterMetaType.

Comment: Is there a required place in the header you need to put it? Under Q_OBJECT? Also, I have switched to using a QVector<QString> and passing that using slots. Based on documentation I've been looking at, this isn't registered automatically either?

Comment: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE should be outside any class declaration. You can use `QStringList` instead which should be registered.

Comment: Turns out the problem was i needed a space between the < and the type within qRegisterMetaType and to keep the macro outside of the class declaration. Now it all works!

Answer (score 1):

Sure that connection is actually made? If there are any problems with connect call, there is usually some debugging output about it on `cerr`.

Secondly, I think you have a typo - if you copied connect call from your code, then know that you have parenthesis missing around SIGNAL - should be

```cxx
connect(&thread, SIGNAL(sendList(string)), this, SLOT(updateTable(string)));
```

Thirdly, what is that you are passing as signal/slot parameter? Is it std::string? Connections between threads must be queued connections. Queued connections can use as parameters only types declared with [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) macro, and registered with [qRegisterMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType). As far as I know, Qt by default doesn't declare those for `std::string`, as it prefers `QString`. If you didn't add those to your code, it might be the reason for failure.