# Connecting signals/slots on separate thread using QtConcurrent::run

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent

In my application I have the following code in a dialog:

```
connect(drive, SIGNAL(FileProgressChanged(Progress)), SLOT(OnFileProgressChanged(Progress)));

QtConcurrent::run(this, &ProgressDialog::PerformOperation, Operation, *Path, OutPath, drive);
```

The PerformOperation function eventually calls to a function in `drive` which emits the signal `FileProgressChanged`, and my `OnFileProgressChanged` function is as follows:

```
void ProgressDialog::OnFileProgressChanged(Progress p)
{
    if (ui->progressCurrent->maximum() != p.Maximium)
        ui->progressCurrent->setMaximum(p.Maximium);

    ui->progressCurrent->setValue(p.Current);

    if (ui->groupBoxCurrent->title().toStdString() != p.FilePath)
        ui->groupBoxCurrent->setTitle(QString::fromStdString(p.FilePath));
}
```

I was doing some reading and saw that [QFuture](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuture.html) and [QFutureWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfuturewatcher.html) support monitoring progress values (which would work great in this situation!), but those cannot be used in conjunction with `QtConcurrent::run`.

How would I go about connecting the signal that gets moved emitted on the separate thread to the slot on my main thread so I can monitor the progress of the function called on the emitter thread?

**Edit -- ** I actually found an error with my code, but it doesn't seem to have an affect.  I forgot to add `this` as an argument after the signal

```
connect(drive, SIGNAL(FileProgressChanged(Progress)), this, SLOT(OnFileProgressChanged(Progress)));
```

Comment: I don't really understand, at first glance this seems like it should work. The thread emits `FileProgressChanged` from `drive`--is `OnFileProgressChanged` being called properly? Emitting a signal from one thread to another thread's slot should work properly (it gets queued).

Comment: On the function that emits, the code is `emit FileProgressChanged(p)`.  If I step into that, it brings me to [this](http://pastebin.com/hhSa8WjV), but my breakpoint at OnFileProgressChanged is never hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `connect()` with `QueuedConnection`, like:

```
connect(drive, SIGNAL(FileProgressChanged(Progress)), this, SLOT(OnFileProgressChanged(Progress)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

The connection should already be queued by default (since the emitter and receiver are in different threads), but this just makes it more explicit.

EDIT: The problem was that the `Progress` type wasn't registered with Qt's meta-object system. Adding `qRegisterMetaType<Progress>("Progress");` fixed the problem.

Comment: No dice.  I did some more searching around and I *believe* the answer lies in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881052/qt-qthread-trouble-using-signal-slot-going-from-worker-to-gui).  The signal/slot connection works fine without the parameters.

Comment: That's possible too. You'll need to have a `qRegisterMetaType<Progress>("Progress");` line somewhere before the `connect()` call. Leaving that out should have thrown an error though (either at compile time or runtime).

Comment: Tested and it was the issue!  Quite a simple fix, thankfully.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Good to hear. I'm surprised it didn't throw errors at runtime though, were you watching the output (like the "Application Output" pane of Qt Creator)? Also, mind marking this as an accepted answer? :)

Comment: I was going to say that I would mark this as the answer, so... yes.  I don't feel like waiting 2 days.  My application had spit out too much info to be able to notice anything in the output, so if it did then it went unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the problem isn't with the cross-thread signal/slot, but instead with the parameter `Progress`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881052/qt-qthread-trouble-using-signal-slot-going-from-worker-to-gui) question's answer goes into further detail, but the solution was found by doing the following in the header file in which Progress was declared:

```
struct Progress
{
    int Current;
    int Maximium;
    std::string FilePath;
    std::string FolderPath;
    int TotalMinimum;
    int TotalMaximum;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Progress)
```

And in my form class:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Progress>();
    connect(Drive, SIGNAL(FileProgressChanged(const Progress&)), this, SLOT(OnFileProgressChanged(const Progress&)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Changing `Progress` to `const Progress&` most likely isn't needed but I left it while testing.