# Emit std::string with QThreads in Qt5. Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Tags: multithreading, types, macros, qt5

**How do i define std::string as a type so i can emit from text from a QThread to another using a queued connection?**

I searched and found many threads solving this issue.

[Here one of the other threads available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698986/emit-stdstring-with-qt-signal)

[Here other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881052/qt-qthread-trouble-using-signal-slot-going-from-worker-to-gui)

But all of them consider the connection as a Qt 4 version. (Signal and slot macros).

Now, after 3 years, with Qt5.2 available, i'm not able to find a solution, even when the documentation says:

[Docs about Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

I have to define the type in my header.
I tried where Q_OBJECT goes, and outside the class. Apparently outside works.

I tried:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE<std::string>();
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string);
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE<std::string>;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE<std::string>(anothername declared for std::string with typedef);
```

All of them gave me errors, from: Syntax error : missing ';' before , to unnable to missing type specifier, int assumed.
The problem is always with this line of code.

and i´m using this in the same class within a method, which registers the type just before connecting the new thread with a queued connection:

```
qRegisterMetaType<std::string>();
QObject::connect(worker, &Raytracer::textEmitted, gui_, &MainWindow::addText, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

What am i doing wrong?

I got to make it work by using QString. But how could i make it work with std::string?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I´ll edit my text. Basically, how to define std::string as a type so i can emit from text from a QThread to another using a queued connection.

Answer (score 2):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` should be placed outside any class or function.

The docs state: [**Ideally, this macro should be placed below the declaration of the class or struct. If that is not possible, it can be put in a private header file which has to be included every time that type is used in a `QVariant`.**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

The correct syntax is `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::string)` without the `;`.

But this is all useless if you are not using templates. As the docs state: [**Declare new types with `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()` to make them available to `QVariant` and other template-based functions. Call `qRegisterMetaType()` to make type available to non-template based functions, such as the queued signal and slot connections.**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details)

So all you need to do is call `qRegisterMetaType`, and you will be able to use `std::string` in your queued connections. Do something like this somewhere before your connect statement:

```
qRegisterMetaType<std::string>("std::string");
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the qmetatype.h header in the file which uses Q_DECLARE_METATYPE.